# Why does Github need to offer a GPG signature feature?

Tags: digital-signature, gnupg, git, github

Github offers users to [sign their work](https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-with-gpg/) using GPG. I guess I missing the bigger picture, though how can people have your SSH keys or your credentials and not your GPG keys. Not sure what kind of layer does it add on top of the regular ssh connection?

How does this help to achieve their goal:

> Use GPG keys to sign your work locally and verify work from trusted collaborators.

Why the authenticated username+password login, exchanged SSH keys with github isn't enough to prevent [masquerade](https://github.com/amoffat/masquerade/commit/9b0562595cc479ac8696110cb0a2d33f8f2b7d29) and implement authorization?

**Edit:**

In fact if you see the comment by [Davorak](https://github.com/amoffat/masquerade/commit/9b0562595cc479ac8696110cb0a2d33f8f2b7d29):

> You can use github's api to identify out who pushed a commit:
>
> Currently the event in question is on page 3 so you can use:
>   https://api.github.com/repos/amoffat/masquerade/events?page=3
>
> It i will roll to further pages as new events come in.

(see the output at the end)

To me it sounds like over-engineering and bad practice, because all the people who don't setup a GPG are still at "risk".

That's what Linus has to [say](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/17).

---

```
{
    "id": "3030685599",
    "type": "PushEvent",
    "actor": {
      "id": 259113,
      "login": "amoffat",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/amoffat",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/259113?"
    },
    "repo": {
      "id": 40194425,
      "name": "amoffat/masquerade",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/amoffat/masquerade"
    },
    "payload": {
      "push_id": 747582733,
      "size": 1,
      "distinct_size": 1,
      "ref": "refs/heads/master",
      "head": "9b0562595cc479ac8696110cb0a2d33f8f2b7d29",
      "before": "2ff8c2e08b0be167a6794a1a03b7a41f0c459141",
      "commits": [
        {
          "sha": "9b0562595cc479ac8696110cb0a2d33f8f2b7d29",
          "author": {
            "email": "torvalds@linux-foundation.org",
            "name": "Linus Torvalds"
          },
          "message": "Enjoy!",
          "distinct": true,
          "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/amoffat/masquerade/commits/9b0562595cc479ac8696110cb0a2d33f8f2b7d29"
        }
      ]
    },
    "public": true,
    "created_at": "2015-08-04T18:44:26Z"
  },
```

Comment: It's not about *your* work but the collaborators, as it says in the link

Comment: @schroeder, but how does it give me more information that isn't implied from their usernames?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPG is used to verify the code in the repository (e.a. you can check who made it afterwards).
SSH is about connectivity (e.a. who is allowed to access the repository).

So using the GPG key (which could be on a SMARTCARD) you can make a authentic commit / tag / release that other people can validate is from you as a canonical source.

This commit will have all the normal things (plaintext user name and email that is free to be set by any client) and a cryptohash that will only validate against the public key of the signer.

This also works over different client's / servers.  So if someone imports the project in Gitlab, the GPG keys (and verification) still works.

The point of using keys (ssh for access and GPG for authenticity) is to provide trust about that code:  it comes from a valid source (SSH key connection) and is from a valid entity (person who signed it with the GPG key).

Comment: If I understand correctly, this could be relevant in a case where I am receiving pushes from others locally, and therefore when I push to GH or some other remote, some of the commits are not mine. The GPG signatures allows both me and GH to verify the identity of the authors of these commits, without either of us trusting anything but the validity of the public keys, correct?

Comment: well not only you.. you basically can trust a commit is actually from a specific person even through some other means (the PGP key validation). since otherwise there is no way to trust the ownership...

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to present an actual situation where that might be relevant. In theory if we only have one central repository everybody pushes to, we control who has access, and we only let people push new commits that they claim to have authored themselves, then we can prevent people from forging commits under others' identity. The issue only arises because of the decentralized nature of git, IIUC.

Comment: @rationalis are you now saying: its not an issue becouse we controle the gitr serve, but it is an issue because git works decentralized?

Answer (score 4):

Since git is decentralized, anyone can forge a commit, and fake the source of the commit, even if they don't have your credentials.

It's really as easy as:

```
git commit --author "Name <email@example.com>"
```

Signing a commit allows its author to prove its authenticity.

Comment: Ok, can you write a proof of concept and submit a commit on behalf an exist github user to any of the google open source project on github? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @0x90: https://github.com/amoffat/masquerade/commit/9b0562595cc479ac8696110cb0a2d33f8f2b7d29

Comment: @0x90 Basically git and ssh are seperated prtocols that work side by side. gpg briddges this gap when used to sign commits.

Comment: @LvB I thought that what github is supposed to do. They could solve it on their end I think.

Comment: github can not verify a commit if it comes in through a third party. git  is decentralized. (e.a. a commit can come though github or directly between developers) github can not 'validate' this direct step that is done by the developers. GPG can be used to validate this intermidiate step. (its done on the Repository itself instead of just the connection)

Comment: @LvB they can see if the sign `git commit -s` is associated with the account's SSH key the commit pushed with. Similar to how google does it over SMTP service.

Comment: the SSH key is not bound to an email and name. GPG is bound to such information. Also GPG key's can be validated externally (e.a. you can get a valid public key from an external source such as a keyserver if its published). and `git commit -s` is not the same as `git commit -S` the latter could be required in the repo settings for each commit (in a specific branch) while the former is project dependent on what it means and has no (inherent) enforcement options.

Answer (score 2):

First things first this is not a "github" feature, it is a git feature.

Git is a distributed version control system designed to allow ad-hoc collaboration. A "main" repository is simply a matter of convention and usage, not a core aspect of git. The result is that tracking the history of the main repository is not a core part of git.

There exists something called the "reflog" which does track the history of a repository but it is intended more as a disaster recovery tool than as a long term record of history. It can only be accessed locally, is not copied to clients, is disabled by default for bare repositories and defaults to a relaveily short expiry time.

The regular author information in a git commit *does not* reliablly identify who created the commit or when. Anyone can create a commit with any authorship information. This may happen maliciously but it can also happen innocently, for example as a result of using import tools to convert other version control systems to git or as a result of rebasing.

So if we want to reliablly identify who created a commit we need another mechanism. One that works in a distributed environment, GPG fits the bill.

---

Getting back to github.

Simply blocking uploads of commits where the author information did not match the identity of the pusher would destroy much of githubs utility. It would make it impossible to maintain history when uploading forks of projects hosted elsewhere. It would make it impossible to maintain history when using github as a mirror while having the projects main repo elsewhere. It would make it impossible to rebase.

So on github like with git in general the author information does not reliablly identify who created the commit. A mechanism for doing that is desirable and git already has a gpg signing mecahnism. Why would github reinvent the wheel?!

Comment: But GitHub has credentials and SSH keys. The question is why GitHub needs this feature, not git. The rest of your answer appears to be answered already

Comment: It's not a feature of github, it's a feature of git that github happened to write some documentation on.

Comment: ... not just wrote documentation for, but according to the link, they incorporated it ... "Once you've set up your GPG key and associated it with your GitHub account and Git"